# AngularJS: Controller is not getting called

Tags: angularjs

I have following html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load staticfiles %}

<html lang="en-US">

<head>
<script src="{% static 'bower_components/angular/angular.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/hearthstone_guides/controllers.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/hearthstone_guides/app.js' %}"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="guideApp">

<p>Name : <input type="text" ng-model="name"></p>
<h1>Hello [[name]]</h1>

<div ng-view></div>

</body>

</html>
```

The `[[ ]]` brackets are the new Symbols for angularJS. I will declare them in my angularJS files. The two way data-binding in combination with the `name` variable (`Hello [[name]]`) was used for the testing of angular and it works. I can ensure it is included properly.

This is my `app.js`

```
var guideApp = angular.module('guideApp', ['ngRoute']);

guideApp
  .config([
    '$routeProvider',
    function($routeProvider) {
      $routeProvider
        .when('/guide/:guideId', {
          controller: 'GuideDetailController',
          templateUrl: '/static/templates/hearthstone_guides/guide-detail.html'
        })
        .otherwise({
          redirectTo: '/'
        });
    }
  ])

  .config([
    '$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
      $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken';
      $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken';
    }
  ])

  .config(function($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol(']]');
  });
```

and this is my `controllers.js`

```
var guideController = angular.module('guideController', []);

guideController.controller('GuideDetailController', [
  '$scope',
  '$routeParams',
  '$http',
  function($scope, $routeParams, $http) {
    $http.get('http://10.0.3.162:8000/api/guides/' + $routeParams.guideId + '/?format=json')
      .success(function(data) {
        console.log('success');
        $scope.guide = data;
      })
      .error(function(data, status) {
        console.error(status, data);
      });
  }
]);
```

When I `console.log('foo');` for instance between `var guideController = angular.module('guideController', []);` and `guideController.controller('GuideDetailController', [...` it works.

Unfortunately neither does `console.log('success');` nor `console.log(status, data);` work.

Edit:

I changed the controller name now to `GuideDetailController` as you suggested but it still doesn't work.

This is the error marked in the firefox developer console:

```
"Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'GuideDetailController' is not a function, got undefined
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.20/ng/areq?p0=GuideDetailController&p1=not%20a                 nanunction%2C%20got%20undefined
minErr/<@http://10.0.3.162:8000/static/bower_components/angular/angular.js:63:12
assertArg@http://10.0.3.162:8000/static/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1590:1
assertArgFn@http://10.0.3.162:8000/static/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1600:1
$ControllerProvider/this.$get</<@http://10.0.3.162:8000/static/bower_components/angular/angular.js:8493:9
ngViewFillContentFactory/<.link@http://10.0.3.162:8000/static/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js:978:26
invokeLinkFn@http://10.0.3.162:8000/static/bower_components/angular/angular.js:8281:9
nodeLinkFn@http://10.0.3.162:8000/static/bower_components/angular/angular.js:7791:1
compositeLinkFn@http://10.0.3.162:8000/static/bower_components/angular/angular.js:7140:13
publicLinkFn@http://10.0.3.162:8000/static/bower_components/angular/angular.js:7019:30
createBoundTranscludeFn/boundTranscludeFn@http://10.0.3.162:8000/static/bower_components/angular/angular.js:7158:1
controllersBoundTransclude@http://10.0.3.162:8000/static/bower_components/angular/angular.js:7818:18
update@http://10.0.3.162:8000/static/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js:936:25
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$broadcast@http://10.0.3.162:8000/static/bower_components/angular/angular.js:14889:15
commitRoute/<@http://10.0.3.162:8000/static/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js:619:15
processQueue@http://10.0.3.162:8000/static/bower_components/angular/angular.js:13318:27
scheduleProcessQueue/<@http://10.0.3.162:8000/static/bower_components/angular/angular.js:13334:27
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$eval@http://10.0.3.162:8000/static/bower_components/angular/angular.js:14570:16
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$digest@http://10.0.3.162:8000/static/bower_components/angular/angular.js:14386:15
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$apply@http://10.0.3.162:8000/static/bower_components/angular/angular.js:14675:13
done@http://10.0.3.162:8000/static/bower_components/angular/angular.js:9725:36
completeRequest@http://10.0.3.162:8000/static/bower_components/angular/angular.js:9915:7
requestLoaded@http://10.0.3.162:8000/static/bower_components/angular/angular.js:9856:1
```

This is how my guide-detail.html file looks like

```
<h1>[[guide.title]]</h1>
<h1>{{guide.title}}</h1>
```

And this is the current results I get when I call this url http://10.0.3.162:8000/#/guide/1

[image]

Comment: why did you remove the guidecontroller module from the dependency again? angular.module('guideApp', ['ngRoute', 'guideController']);

Comment: Ah damn, the first answer  (deleted now) told me to do so.. Didn't revert it yet... Now it works!! Thank you

Comment: @Sajeetharan I already marked JBNizets answer as the best answer because his answer was correct too and he helped me a lot in the process of finding the error :)

Comment: yes true ! :) no problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should not use the minified versions of the libraries while developing.

Second, your unique route is configured to use the controller `'guideController'`. But you have no such controller. The only controller defined is named `'GuideDetailController'`.

`'guideController'` is not a controller. It's a module.

Comment: I'd prefer not having to guess. Replace the minified files by the non-minified ones, refresh, and post the actual error message you get. What you posted is a line of the minified code, which is completely useless. Also, what is the url in the address bar, because all the urls except /guide/xxx redirect to /, but you haven't configured any route for /.

Comment: Your page loads the script `controllers.js`, but your file is named (according to your description) `controller.js`.

Comment: Edit your question and repost the new code of both files.

Comment: It works now @jbnizet! I removed `guideController` from `var guideApp = angular.module('guideApp', ['ngRoute', 'guideController']);` because the very first answer posted here, told me to do so and I didn't reverted it yet, since the answer got deleted. Thank you very much for your awesome help!

Answer (score 3):

You have put module name as a controller in the route config

Change **From:**

```
.config([
    '$routeProvider',
    function($routeProvider) {
      $routeProvider
        .when('/guide/:guideId', {
          controller: 'guideController',
          templateUrl: '/static/templates/hearthstone_guides/guide-detail.html'
        })
        .otherwise({
          redirectTo: '/'
        });
    }
  ])
```

**To:**

```
config([
        '$routeProvider',
        function($routeProvider) {
          $routeProvider
            .when('/guide/:guideId', {
              controller: 'GuideDetailController',
              templateUrl: '/static/templates/hearthstone_guides/guide-detail.html'
            })
            .otherwise({
              redirectTo: '/'
            });
        }
      ])
```